# OpenLayers map: animation lost if map centered with: fromLonLat()

Tags: openlayers, geojson, mapping

I have a **OpenLayers** map with animated features (points that appear on the map) here: [codesandbox.io/s/ol-map-7-2-2-npm-hdsssj](https://codesandbox.io/s/ol-map-7-2-2-npm-hdsssj?file=/main.js)

The map takes source from [topo.son file at line 59](https://codesandbox.io/s/ol-map-7-2-2-npm-hdsssj?file=/main.js:1549-1633) (or from [geojson at line 60](https://codesandbox.io/s/ol-map-7-2-2-npm-hdsssj?file=/main.js:1633-1719)).
Points are comes from [geojson file at line 23](https://codesandbox.io/s/ol-map-7-2-2-npm-hdsssj?file=/main.js:741-770).

### The problem is:

Animation is lost if i center the map like this:

```
center: fromLonLat([-628.246521, 67.049039])
```

or like this:

```
center: transform([-628.246521, 67.049039], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
```

My map is centered properly, but animation is lost in this case.

##### But if i center the map just like this:

(you can toggle the [comment at the line 101](https://codesandbox.io/s/ol-map-7-2-2-npm-hdsssj?file=/main.js:2763-2806))

```
center: [-628.246521, 67.049039],
```

the animation appears on points, but the map is not centered.

How can I get a centered map and animation at the same time?

Comment: The animation is not working in wrapped coordinates.  Change the longitude to be in the range -180 to +180 (i.e. `720 - 628.246521`) and you will seen animation.

Comment: Oh, thanks, it was so simply 
I spent several days looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

With gratitude to [@Mike](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/102658/mike) and his comment, the solution is:
center the map with longitude `720 - 628.246521` instead of `-628.246521`, like this:

```
center: fromLonLat([720 - 628.246521, 67.049039]),
```